# Missing method in Visual Studio when trying to process OLAP cube

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, ssms, olap

I have got `SSMS v 17.9.1`  and `Visual Studio 2017 v 17.9.1` installed. I have created many olap cubes so far but today a new issue surfaced. Trying to process the newly created cube, I've got  the following error

> Method not found: 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.CDataContainer.get_OlapServer()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the v2.5 of the Analysis Services Projects extensions for Visual Studio. There is a note on [this page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects) with a link to the v2.2 download suggesting that people downgrade to this version until Microsoft can fix the 2.5 release.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you're deploying to the correct version of Analysis Services. It's a project level setting you can adjust. Also, make sure that your user (the user conducting the deployment) has been added as an admin on the instance.

H/T: https://www.reddit.com/r/SQLServer/comments/anwfep/getting_error_when_trying_to_deploy_ssas_project/

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved problem by uninstall SQL Server Data Tools, install previous (15.8.2) version and disable SSDT automatic update.

Link for previous SSDT versions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017